# Как использовать буферизацию вывода?

Tags: php

Сколько ни читал, не пойму целесообразность использования функций буферизации - ob_start() и последующей ob_end_clean(). Я понимаю, что так буферизируется информация, которую сервер впоследствии выбросит клиенту (например, произведя над ней некоторые манипуляции). Однако, не проще ли просто весь html-код собирать  в переменную,обрабатывая данные как душе угодно, а затем готовый блок выводить в браузер? Не в этом ли состоит сущность MVC? Или я что-то упустил из виду?

Comment: иногда это невозможно, скажем вы адаптируете под новые нужды весьма старый код, а может быть он просто обфусцирован и вы не можете получить внятный исходник, ну и иногда проще  написать 

    ob_start();
    include "view.php";
    ob_end_flush();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Я понимаю, что так буферизируется информация, которую сервер впоследствии выбросит клиенту (например, произведя над ней некоторые манипуляции).

Да, например, рендер вьюхи. Идиотский пример: у вас есть вывод контроллера, который должен присутствовать в модальном окне на странице другого контроллера, причем присутствовать с момента загрузки (а не подгружаться через AJAX). Такая техника помогает развязать руки в некоторых редких, но неприятных ситуациях.

> Однако, не проще ли просто весь html-код собирать в переменную,обрабатывая данные как душе угодно, а затем готовый блок выводить в браузер? Не в этом ли состоит сущность MVC?

Сущность MVC к этому никакого отношения не имеет. Паттерн MVC будет валидным и с буферизацией, и с мгновенным выводом (что тоже, на самом деле, буферизация, потому что первый буфер открывает сам PHP еще до того момента, как ваш скрипт начнет работать).
Иногда html-код иначе не собрать в переменную, например, вывод var_dump. Если вы зависите от чужой кривой библиотеки, то, возможно, без буфера вообще не обойтись.